# How to render an array of JSX elements (React components)

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

I'm trying to render an array of named react components, say `<Foo />`, `<Bar />`, and `<Baz />`,for example.

```
const rendered = [];
const getItems = this.props.itemslist.map((item, key) => {
const TYPE = item.type;
rendered.push(<TYPE data-attributes={attributes} key={key} />);
});
return (
  <Grid>
    <Row>
    {rendered}
    </Row>
  </Grid>
);
```

I can iterate over my array and see in the console the array of elements, but they are rendered as empty html elements "`<foo></foo><bar></bar><baz></baz>`", and not the actual components.
Why is this happening and, more importantly, how can I get the COMPONENTS to render?

Comment: yes, it's a string:

Comment: @brainstormtrooper Dont store string in `item.type`. Instead store component itself.

Comment: `itemslist: [
    {
      type: 'Foo',
    },
    {
      type: 'Bar',
    },
    {
      type: 'Baz',
    },
    ]`

Comment: @Prakashsharma, How can I do that? I have a config file in javascript... I need to be able to iterate and configure my components...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use component instead of string in `item.type` like this

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

[ { type: Foo, }, { type: Bar, }, { type: Baz}]
```

**UPDATE:**

If you do not have component reference in advance then use a mapping object which convert your string to component reference like this

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

const mapper = {
  Foo: Foo,
  Bar: Bar,
}

// Then use it like this

const getItems = this.props.itemslist.map((item, key) => {
    const Type = mapper[item.type];
    rendered.push(<Type data-attributes={attributes} key={key} />);
});
```

Comment: @brainstormtrooper I am not sure i got you. My point is that from string, you cannot render component. If you do not have component reference then just create a map object which map your string to component.

Comment: @brainstormtrooper See this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365

Comment: @brainstormtrooper Also this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365#issuecomment-218409353

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is see if an incorrect use of `.map`. Remember that `.map` traverses each array element and changes them. Right now, you are using it as if it were `.forEach`.

Your code should look more like this:

```
const getItems = this.props.itemslist.map((item, key) => {
  const TYPE = item.type;
  return <TYPE data-attributes={attributes} key={key} />
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html#creating-a-reactelement) for creating the React element with a dynamic name. Also make sure to import those components.

```
const rendered = [];
const getItems = this.props.itemslist.map((item, key) => {
    const component = React.createElement(item.type, {data-attributes: attributes, key: key}, null);
    rendered.push(component);
});
return (
  <Grid>
    <Row>
    {rendered}
    </Row>
  </Grid>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but I get the same result :-(

Comment: Are you string beginning with upperCase character, else it wont be treated as a react component