# Dynamic Addition to html element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to dynamically add few div elements just when component is mounted. I tried with following code

```
<div className="resumebuilder__structure" ref="panel_holder">
</div>
```

My function which is called in lifecycle hook

```
getPanels = () => {
  return this.props
    .resumeTemplate
    .roughTemplateStructure
    .roughScale.map((roughS) => {
      const uid = uuid();
      this.updatePanelInTemplate(uid);
      const elem = <div ref={uid} className={roughS.class} ></div>;
      return elem;
    });
}
```

lifecycle method

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.panel_holder.appendChild(this.getPanels());
}
```

But I am getting following error

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Does anyone has any idea?

---- Update--

Although I continued with other methods but the answer is still not found. Please do comment if you know anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to put the components in an array in the parent's state. Then render all the components in that array.

Comment: I want to access those div every now and then how do I access it then?

Comment: what do you mean by access ?

Comment: I will dynamically add some more div but on user click

Comment: yes you will add your components to the array and it will rerender using setState().

Comment: used case is like: In the beginning I will add some partition in the div which I am trying now and then after when user drag some component over these divs those components will get added as child to particular div element

Comment: I think i am getting your point. But that is alternate way. Question is how can we use ref for this?

Comment: I got some different error when I stored in array and then rendered it

Comment: here somehow how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422833/how-to-render-an-array-of-jsx-elements-react-components